# An internal server error has occurred while uploading attachment to email

Tags: email, attachment

I am getting this error below while attaching a file to an email in salesforce in the account and person screen. The error shows after i browse the file and after i click "attach to email". Not sure what changed as it was working fine last week. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

"An internal server error has occurred
An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!

Error ID: 864267632-18230 (1847329934)"

Comment: Are you on NA9? There is currently an [issue](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status/) on it.

Comment: The issue on NA9 is now resolved.

Comment: @Imran were you able to resolve this error? Having the same problem in one of custom visualforce pages.